# React useEffect Hook does not get called, Redux action does not get fired

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Whenever I go to my EditProduct page I am calling useEffect to get the product that has the ID of match.params.id. The problem is the hook is not getting called. I do not know honestly why that is, or why it would be at all, since i am calling it how it should be called. I am also getting a type error saying it can not read prop name of undefined, obvsiously if the product is null it can not read the name of it.
I am also seeing in my redux devtools also that no actions get fired, although loadUser is an action that should always get fired when the site re renders/mount, which i did set up in app.js.

I will paste some of my codes below and a github repo.

https://github.com/tigerabrodi/eBuy

editProduct component

```
import React, {Fragment, useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {withRouter} from "react-router-dom";
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import {editProduct, getProduct} from '../../redux/product/product.actions';
import Spinner from '../layout/Spinner';

const EditProduct = ({history, editProduct, match, product: {loading, product}}) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        getProduct(match.params.id);
    }, [getProduct, match.params.id]);

    const [formData,
        setFormData] = useState({name: product.name, description: product.description, price: product.price, image: ""});
    const [showImage, setShowImage] = useState(false);
    const [imageName, setImageName] = useState("");

    const onChangeImage = e => {
        setFormData({...formData, image: e.target.files[0]});
        setShowImage(true);
        setImageName(e.target.files[0].name);
    }

    const onChange = e => setFormData({
        ...formData,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });

        const onSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        editProduct(formData, history, match.params.id);
        }

    const {name, description, price} = formData;

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                {loading && (
                    <Spinner />
                )}
                    <div className="col text-info font-weight-bold m-2">
                    *- All Fields Requried!
                        <form onSubmit={e => onSubmit(e)}>
                        <div className="form-group m-2">
                        <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Products Name" name="name" value={name} onChange={e => onChange(e)} className="form-control" required/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group m-2">
                        <label htmlFor="price">Price</label>
                        <input type="number" name="price" placeholder="Enter Products Price" value={price} onChange={e => onChange(e)}  className="form-control" required/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="custom-file m-2">
                        <input type="file"  onChange={e => onChangeImage(e)}  class="custom-file-input bg-info" required/>
                        <label class="custom-file-label">{showImage ? imageName : "Upload Image"}</label>
                      </div>
                        <div className="form-group m-2">
                        <label htmlFor="title">Description</label>
                        <textarea name="description" onChange={e => onChange(e)} placeholder="Enter Products description" value={description} className="form-control" required/>
                        </div>
                        <input type="submit" value="Add Product" className="btn btn-block btn-info"/>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </Fragment>
    );
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    product: state.product,
    auth: state.auth
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {editProduct})(withRouter(EditProduct));
```

app.js

```
import './App.css';
import React, {Fragment, useEffect} from 'react';
import {Provider} from "react-redux";
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch} from "react-router-dom";
import store from "./redux/store";
import setAuthToken from './utils/setAuthToken';
import { loadUser } from './redux/auth/auth.actions';
import Navbar from './components/layout/Navbar';
import Landing from './components/layout/Landing';
import Alert from './components/layout/Alert';
import Register from './components/auth/Register';
import Login from './components/auth/Login';
import PrivateRoute from './components/routing/PrivateRoute';
import Dashboard from './components/dashboard/Dashboard';
import CreateProduct from './components/product-forms/CreateProduct';
import Products from './components/products/Products';
import EditProduct from './components/product-forms/EditProduct';


if (localStorage.token) {
    setAuthToken(localStorage.token)
}


const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    store.dispatch(loadUser());
  }, []);

  return (  
    <Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
    <Fragment>
    <Navbar />
    <Alert />
    <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
    <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
    <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
    <PrivateRoute exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
    <PrivateRoute exact path="/add-product" component={CreateProduct} />
    <PrivateRoute exact path="/products" component={Products} />
    <PrivateRoute exact path="/products/edit/:id" component={EditProduct} />
    </Switch>
    </Fragment>
    </Router>
    </Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

product actions

```js
import {ProductActionTypes} from "./product.types"
import {setAlert} from "../alert/alert.actions"
import axios from "axios"


// Add A Product
export const addProduct = (productData, history) => async dispatch => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("name", productData.name);
    formData.append("description", productData.description);
    formData.append("price", productData.price);
    formData.append("image", productData.image);
    try {
        const res = await axios.post("/products", formData);
        dispatch({
            type: ProductActionTypes.ADD_PRODUCT,
            payload: res.data
        });
        history.push("/dashboard");
        dispatch(setAlert("Product created successfully", "success"))
    } catch (err) {
        const errors = err.response.data.errors;
        if (errors) {
          errors.forEach(error => dispatch(setAlert(error.msg, 'danger')));
        }
        dispatch({
        type: ProductActionTypes.PRODUCT_ERROR,
        payload: {msg: err.response.statusText, status: err.response.status}
        })
    }
}

// Get all products
export const getAllProducts = page => async dispatch => {
    try {
        const res = await axios.get(`/products?page=${page}`);
        dispatch({
            type: ProductActionTypes.GET_PRODUCTS,
            payload: {products: res.data.products, totalItems: res.data.totalItems}
        })
    } catch (err) {
        dispatch({
            type: ProductActionTypes.PRODUCT_ERROR,
            payload: err
            })
    }
}

// Delete a product
export const deleteSingleProduct = id => async dispatch => {
    try {
        await axios.delete(`/products/${id}`);
        dispatch({
            type: ProductActionTypes.DELETE_PRODUCT,
            payload: id
        });
        dispatch(setAlert("Product deleted successfully", "success"))
    } catch (err) {
        dispatch({
            type: ProductActionTypes.PRODUCT_ERROR,
            payload: {msg: err.response.statusText, status: err.response.status}
            })
    }
}

// Get A Single users products
export const getUserProducts = (id, page) => async dispatch => {
    try {
        const res = await axios.get(`/products/${id}?page=${page}`);
        dispatch({
            type: ProductActionTypes.GET_PRODUCTS,
            payload: res.data
        })
    } catch (err) {
        dispatch({
            type: ProductActionTypes.PRODUCT_ERROR,
            payload: {msg: err.response.statusText, status: err.response.status}
            })
    }
}

// Edit a Product
export const editProduct = (productData, history, id) => async dispatch => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("name", productData.name);
    formData.append("description", productData.description);
    formData.append("price", productData.price);
    formData.append("image", productData.image);
    try {
        const res = await axios.put(`/products/edit/${id}`, formData);
        dispatch({
            type: ProductActionTypes.UPDATE_PRODUCT,
            payload: res.data
        });
        dispatch(setAlert("Product updated successfully", "success"))
        history.push("/dashboard")
    } catch (err) {
        dispatch({
            type: ProductActionTypes.PRODUCT_ERROR,
            payload: {msg: err.response.statusText, status: err.response.status}
            })
    }
}

// Get a single product by ID
export const getProduct = id => async dispatch => {
    try {
        const res = await axios.get(`/products/product/${id}`);
        dispatch({
            type: ProductActionTypes.GET_PRODUCT,
            payload: res.data
        });
    } catch (err) {
        dispatch({
            type: ProductActionTypes.PRODUCT_ERROR,
            payload: {msg: err.response.statusText, status: err.response.status}
            });
    }
}
```

product reducer

```js
import {ProductActionTypes} from "./product.types";

const initialState = {
    products: [],
    totalProducts: null,
    product: null,
    loading: true,
    error: {}
}

const productReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    const {payload, type} = action;
    switch(type) {
        case ProductActionTypes.GET_PRODUCTS:
            return {
                ...state,
                products: payload.products,
                totalProducts: payload.totalItems,
                loading: false
            }
            case ProductActionTypes.GET_PRODUCT:
                return {
                    ...state,
                    product: payload,
                    loading: false
                }
        case ProductActionTypes.ADD_PRODUCT:
            return {
                ...state,
                products: [payload, ...state.products],
                loading: false
            }
            case ProductActionTypes.UPDATE_PRODUCT:
                return {
                    ...state,
                    products: state.products.map(product => product._id === payload.id ? {product: payload.product} : product),
                    loading: false
                }
            case ProductActionTypes.DELETE_PRODUCT:
                return {
                    ...state,
                    products: state.products.filter(product => product._id !== payload),
                    loading: false
                }
            case ProductActionTypes.PRODUCT_ERROR: 
            return {
                ...state,
                error: payload,
                loading: false
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default productReducer
```

auth actions

```js
import axios from "axios";
import {setAlert} from "../alert/alert.actions"
import {AuthActionTypes} from "./auth.types"
import setAuthToken from "../../utils/setAuthToken"

// Load User
export const loadUser = () => async dispatch => {
    if (localStorage.token) {
      setAuthToken(localStorage.token);
    }

    try {
      const res = await axios.get('/auth');

      dispatch({
        type: AuthActionTypes.USER_LOADED,
        payload: res.data
      });
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch({
        type: AuthActionTypes.AUTH_ERROR
      });
    }
  };

// Register User
export const register = ({ name, email, password }) => async dispatch => {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    };

    const body = JSON.stringify({ name, email, password });

    try {
      const res = await axios.post('/auth/signup', body, config);

      dispatch({
        type: AuthActionTypes.REGISTER_SUCCESS,
        payload: res.data
      });

      dispatch(loadUser());
    } catch (err) {
      const errors = err.response.data.errors;

      if (errors) {
        errors.forEach(error => dispatch(setAlert(error.msg, 'danger')));
      }

      dispatch({
        type: AuthActionTypes.REGISTER_FAIL
      });
    }
  };

    // Login User
export const login = (email, password) => async dispatch => {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    };

    const body = JSON.stringify({ email, password });

    try {
      const res = await axios.post('/auth/signin', body, config);

      dispatch({
        type: AuthActionTypes.LOGIN_SUCCESS,
        payload: res.data
      });

      dispatch(loadUser());
    } catch (err) {
      const errors = err.response.data.errors;
      if (errors) {
        errors.forEach(error => dispatch(setAlert(error.msg, 'danger')));
      }

      dispatch({
        type: AuthActionTypes.LOGIN_FAIL
      });
    }
  };

    // Logout / Clear Profile
export const logout = () => dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: AuthActionTypes.LOGOUT });
  };
```

auth reducer

```js
import {AuthActionTypes} from "./auth.types";


const initialState = {
    token: localStorage.getItem("token"),
    isAuthenticated: null,
    loading: true,
    user: null
}


const authReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    const {type, payload} = action;
    switch (type) {
        case AuthActionTypes.USER_LOADED:
          return {
            ...state,
            isAuthenticated: true,
            loading: false,
            user: payload
          };
        case AuthActionTypes.REGISTER_SUCCESS:
        case AuthActionTypes.LOGIN_SUCCESS:
          localStorage.setItem('token', payload.token);
          return {
            ...state,
            ...payload,
            isAuthenticated: true,
            loading: false
          };
        case AuthActionTypes.REGISTER_FAIL:
        case AuthActionTypes.AUTH_ERROR:
        case AuthActionTypes.LOGIN_FAIL:
        case AuthActionTypes.LOGOUT:
        case AuthActionTypes.ACCOUNT_DELETED:
          case AuthActionTypes.USER_ERROR:
          localStorage.removeItem('token');
          return {
            ...state,
            token: null,
            isAuthenticated: false,
            loading: false
          };
        default:
          return state;
    }
}

export default authReducer
```

Comment: You probably want to have `onChangeImage`, `onChange` and `onSubmit` to be defined with `useCallback` so that you're not getting a brand new function reference every render (which causes unnecessary re-renders).

Comment: but when should i call my useEffecy and where

Comment: could you perhaps modify my code :( i also noticed i forgot to put getProduct as a prop which i tried doing

Comment: i would seriously love to get this one solved :c

Comment: Two people have tried to assist you, SO isn't really the place to drop your application and ask for someone else to fix it for you. My answer _should_ solve it, and you said it didn't. So I told you that without knowing what you changed to get to where you were testing with my suggestion I can't help you further. You never replied. You need to put effort into solving it, we won't solve it for you. We're here to help and we've helped. Your turn to put in some additional effort.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the `useEffect` is firing, you should put a log in there and I guarantee you'll see it.

What it looks to me, with the code you posted is that you're taking in the *action creator*, `getProduct` and calling it in the hook -- and you're not seeing it dispatch in the store and you're not seeing the work it's doing fire. Based on those issues, it's because you're *not dispatching the action*.

You need to use `react-redux`'s `connect` to connect the component to either get `dispatch`, or pre-bind the action creator to be dispatched, or use `useDispatch` to get a reference to dispatch and then you need to wrap that `dispatch(getProduct(...))`.

Unrelated, if `getDispatch` is a static function (meaning the definition never changes) you would not need, nor should you, pass it as a dependency to `useEffect`. That dependency array for hooks is not for all the things you reference in the hook, but for all the values that, when they change, should cause the hook to re-run. In other words, if you just boil it down to the product ID then anytime the component is rendered with a new product ID that effect hook would rerun the function. And since `getProduct` is imported and never reassigned or changed, then `useEffect` will never re-trigger on that value so you can remove it from the dependency array.

To follow that I do recommend putting `dispatch` in the dependency array because `react-redux` does not note in their documentation that the reference to `dispatch` is static therefore you should not assume that it will not change.

Comment: idk tbh what to do, it is still not firing off the action and not working....

Comment: Without knowing what changes you tried exactly to determine it's still not working I can't give you any more advice. Based on the code above this is a major issue. I can guarantee you that `useEffect` is not the problem -- it would be around the usage of it (I see this a lot, and deal with these kinds of problems every day).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the `withRouter` HOC is "blocked" by the `connect` HOC and doesn't pass the router's data to your component.

You should change the order of HOCS (`withRouter` first):

```
withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(EditProduct))
```

Comment: You can also use the `compose` function from `redux` to clean up multiple HOCs: `compose(withRouter, connect(mapStateToProps))(EditProduct)`

Comment: Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::9045 this is what i get now

Comment: though tbh idk what to do i think im just gonna head to bed and make sure to get some proper sleep ....